# hitTestObject, stopDrag stops drag on two movieclips even though function states one movieclip to stop drag

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flash-cs5, movieclip, hittest

I have a function that states when movieclip1 is dragged and hits a line then it stops the drag, however it seems to stop the entire drag function in the swf on the other movieclips even though they arent called in the function. Can somebody please help me with this.

Regards
T

Here is the code:

```
 function hitTest(event:Event):void
 {
 if (movieclip1.hitTestObject(line))
   {
 movieclip1.stopDrag();
   }
 else
   {

   }
 }
```

Comment: It's helpful that you posted code, but you should probably post more so that we don't have to make assumptions about how your code is written. For example, can you post the code that starts the drag?

Comment: Try replacing the code in the `hitTest()` function with the following: `var displayObject:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(e.currentTarget); if(displayObject.hitTestObject) displayObject.stopDrag();`

Comment: Also you should probably change the `hitTest()` function's name to `onClick()` or `onMovieClipClick()` or `clickHandler()` just to adhere to common AS3 naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely positive you only have *one* instance of movieclip1 on your stage? Definitely double check. Are you creating them dynamically, or are they preloaded when your SWF loads?

If they're preloaded:
Perhaps during testing you made some quick copies of it, and now those copies have the same name and they're all responding the same. That's my first guess.

If they're loaded dynamically:
Check the function where they're being created. If you're naming them in a loop (with a number on the end like the above), be sure that you're properly increasing the numeric value used on the end.